# Using Knex - How to retrieve Multiple result sets

Tags: knex.js

I'm using MSSQL, I have a stored proc which is returning multiple result sets (1 for data and 1 for record count) when I call this stored proc with knex.raw, Knex is only returning the first result set. How can I retrieve other record count result sets using Knex + Node.js?

{
    "data": [{"ID": 6344,"RequestID": 910846045,"Requester": "XXXXXXX",
            "Started": "09/25/2018",
            "Completed": "09/25/2018"
        }
 {
           "ID": 6345,
            "RequestID": 910846046,
            "Requester": "XXXXXXX",
            "Started": "09/25/2018",
            "Completed": "09/25/2018"
        }
    ],
    "RecordCnt": 2
}

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Dipal - Please refer the James solution as its worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

I've just came across this very same problem migrating from using `mssql` to `knex`.

The simple answer is knex doesn't support this out the box, however, the underlying MSSQL client (tedious) does. If you are familiar with the `mssql` client, you can simply acquire a connection from the pool and then use it as you normally would to [execute a stored procedure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#execute-procedure-callback) e.g.

```
const connection = await knex.client.acquireConnection();
const result = await connection.request()
  .input('parameter', value)
  .execute('[procedure_name]');
knex.client.releaseConnection(connection); // we don't have to wait for this
```

The last line is very important, as we are manually acquiring a connection we are responsible for releasing it back to the pool. Failure to do this will lead to pool starvation and new requests will eventually start to fail (based on the size of your pool).

Comment: Yes your solution worked well. I have used MSSQL Client for multiple recordsets

Comment: @Sumathi feel free to mark this as the answer if that is the case, it may help future users

Comment: You have a typo in your answer. I think it should be "knex.client.acquireConnection()".

Comment: Anyway, I could not get it running with knex 0.95.4 and mssql 6.3.1. Guess this way is not supported anymore.